# Q. How to query a model, in a one-to-many relationship, return associated records?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

**Models**:

- Purchase Orders
- Items

**Relationship**:
Purchase Orders (one) <--> (many) Items

**Ownership:**
Purchase Orders (Owner) -> Items

I am able to return all records from Items model using this code:

```js
//Query Items and return records related to each Purchase Order.
  var query = app.models.Items.newQuery();
  var allItems = query.run();
```

But how do I return only the items associated with each purchase order record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass the purchase order record key to your query and filter items by it. For example:

```
  function getPurchaseOrderItems(purchaseOrderRecordKey){
      //Query Items and return records related to each Purchase Order.
      var query = app.models.Items.newQuery();
      query.filters.PurchaseOrders._key._equals = purchaseOrderRecordKey;
      var allItems = query.run();
  }
```

I recommend you to consult the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server#working_with_relationships) for a more detailed explanation. That way you'll get a deeper and better understanding on how to work with relations.